# Terminal Open Safari with Website

Tags: terminal, safari, big-sur

```
open /Applications/"Safari.app" "https://plarium.com/en/strategy-games/vikings-war-of-clans/"
```

This opens both Safari and Chrome, Chrome being my default browser

How can I open specific pages in Safari?

Answer (score 2):

```
open -a /Applications/"Safari.app" "https://plarium.com/en/strategy-games/vikings-war-of-clans/"
```

Note the inclusion of the `-a` flag.